# Посоветуйте как сделать рефакторинг?

Tags: java, android

Я по промеру сделал общий запрос пермишенов и вот `callback` принимаю ответ исходя из примера выглядит он так

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {

            Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();
            // Initial
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);

            // Fill with results
            for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            }

            // Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // All Permissions Granted
                UtilClass.goToNextActivity(WelcomePage.this, AuthorizationActivity.class);
            } else {

                // Permission Denied
                Log.e(MY_LOG, "Some Permission is Denied");
                UtilClass.goToNextActivity(WelcomePage.this, AuthorizationActivity.class);
            }
        }
        break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

Тут у меня несколько вопросов

Создаем мы `Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();` я так понимаю для удобочитаемости, потом заполняем его теми пермишенами которые мы запрашивали и + как `value` ставим сразу значение которое мы ожидаем получить

```
perms.put(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Далее следует цикл который уже сверху перезаписывает те значения которые мы только что вложили (не понятно зачем мы их туда вкладывали)

```
for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
                perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
            }
```

Почему сразу не сделать этот цикл и записать сразу истинные значения которые возвращает `callback` ? Зачем эти 2 строки

```
perms.put(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

И потом следует финальная проверка

```
// Check for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // All Permissions Granted
                UtilClass.goToNextActivity(WelcomePage.this, AuthorizationActivity.class);
            } else {

                // Permission Denied
                Log.e(MY_LOG, "Some Permission is Denied");
                UtilClass.goToNextActivity(WelcomePage.this, AuthorizationActivity.class);
            }
```

Если все пермишены были подтверждены то делаем одно если не все, то другое..

Я вот не могу придумать как это можно упростить, чтоб не указывать вот тут

```
if (perms.get(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && perms.get(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
```

при добавлении нового пермишена новую проверку(а если у меня их 10)...

Может цикл какой нибудь...

Как это красиво сделать?

Answer (score 1):

По поводу

```
perms.put(Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
perms.put(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
```

Дело в том, что если, допустим, GET_ACCOUNTS уже приложению разрешен, то он не будет повторно запрошен и не попадет в

```
@NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults
```

А так, как проверка далее проводится по двум этим пермишенам, то во избежании NPE он инициализируется заранее положительным результатом

В целом логика такая - для реализации какого-то конкретного функционала приложения необходим свой набор разрешений.

Допустим у вас приложение может делать фотки и получать уведомления от сервера. Это два разных функционала требующие разных разрешений. Соответственно, теоретически, вы должны проверять и, если надо, запрашивать разрешения у пользователя в тот момент, когда он планирует конкретным функционалом воспользоваться. При старте приложения вы спрашиваете про уведомления, при нажатии кнопки "фото" - спрашиваете про камеру.

А так как callback у вас один - логика обработки разделяется с помощью requestCode. А уж как дальше уже работает сама эта логика - это уже на ваш выбор. Хотите в цикле, хотите switch'ом, хотите if'ом проверяйте.